# i got an error using pentaho with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, kettle

I want to load a datamart dimension using Pentaho Data Integration. 
I joined a capture of the transformation in the message with the error that i get. please help ?

[image: The error]

[image: The transformation]

Comment: Can you include just the text, or a new screen shot that doesn't cut off some of the messages?.

Comment: Please show the configuration of the dimension update step. Suspect something is wrong in here.

Answer (score 2):

read again the error message, your query has a syntax error near AND